# UWP MediaPlayerElement in WindowsXamlHost. MFPlat.dll error

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, ms-media-foundation, windows-community-toolkit

we are using a UWP MediaPlayerElement added to a WindowsXamlHost Control for a WPF Video Player App.
After some time of playing a 0xc0000005 error is thrown by a MFPlat.dll and the App crashed.
I found out that the 0xc0000005 exception stands for a memory access violation and the MFPlat.dll is part ob the Windows Media Foundation.

Has anyone ever had such a problem and maybe a solution for that?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03e3s.png]

**EDIT:**
The error comes only when the videos have a 4K/UHD resolution, seemingly.

Comment: If this is consistent and reproducible you could probably take a dump and submit a bug report. This looks like a bug in underlying API (Media Foundation API) but this image is insufficient for any meaningful troubleshooting.

Comment: @RomanR. Thx for comment. 
Unfortunately the error is not consistent and not intentionally reproducible. The Software is running and at some point it crashed, sometimes after 1 hour, somtimes after 8 hours. The only constant is that it happens. The event log entry is the only thing i have.